# En llamada a función en C++, el compilador muestra el error xxxxx was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Al ejecutar el compilador me tira 3 errores

> error:'raices' was not declared in this scope
>
> error:'discrim was not declared in this scope
>
> error: could not convert 'make_tuple({float&, float&)&& ...) r2)' from
> 'tuple<float, float>' to 'tuple'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

tuple<float>raices(float a, float b, float c){
    float d= discrim(a,b,c);
    float r1= (-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    float r2= (-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    return make_tuple(r1,r2);
}

float discrim(float a, float b, float c){
    float d= b*b-4*a*c;
    return d;
}

int main() {
    float a,b,c;
    cin>> a>>b>>c;
    float r1,r2;
    tie(r1,r2) = raices(a,b,c);
    cout<< r1<<" "<<r2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Has ganado tu primera medalla de experiencia como copy-paste "developer": Cuando copies el código, no olvides copiar también la declaración de variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

> '...' was not declared in this scope

Se da porque intentas usar una función o una variable que no fue previamente declarada.

Por ejemplo, tienes ese problema con la función `discrim` porque se define luego de la función `raiz`, donde se usa.

Para resolverlo puedes definirla antes o proveer una declaración antes.

Diferencia clave, en una declaración le dices al compilador que una función existe:

```
 float discrim(float a, float b, float c);
```

Mientras que en una definición incluyes el cuerpo de la función:

```
 float discrim(float a, float b, float c){
     ...
 }
```

**Importante:** puedes repetir una declaración todas las veces que quieras pero no una definición. Si repites una definición obtendrás un error de parte del linker ya que no puede elegir cuál definición usar.

---

El último error se debe a qué devuelves una tupla de 2 elementos (`tuple<float, float>`) pero no coincide con el tipo de retorno (`tuple<float>`).

---

Corrigiendo los problemas mencionados, obtendrás un código como este:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

float discrim(float a, float b, float c);

tuple<float, float> raices(float a, float b, float c){
    float d = discrim(a,b,c);
    float r1 = (-b + sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    float r2 = (-b - sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    return make_tuple(r1,r2);
}

float discrim(float a, float b, float c){
    float d= b*b - 4*a*c;
    return d;
}

int main() {
    float a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    float r1, r2;
    tie(r1, r2) = raices(a, b, c);
    cout<< r1 << " " << r2;
    return 0;
}
```